# Need Help: AttributeError: "SQLAlchemy" object has no attribute 'Models'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

AttributeError: sqlalchemy object has no attribute "Models" error is occurring. I already installed all requirements like pip install sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopy2-binary. this file name is create.py

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from models import *

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALchemy_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
app.config["SQLALchemy_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)

def main():
   db.create_all()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        main()
```

this file is models.py

```
 from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db=SQLAlchemy()

class Flight(db.Models):
    __tablename__ = "flights"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    origin = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    destination = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    duration = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

class Passenger(db.Models):
    __tablename__ = "passengers"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    flight_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("flights.id", 
nullable=False))
```

output is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create.py", line 4, in 
    from models import *
  File "D:\web\flaskrun\models.py", line 5, in 
    class Flight(db.Models):
AttributeError: 'SQLAlchemy' object has no attribute 'Models'

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice, but edit your existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58546872/attributeerror-sqlalchemy-object-has-no-attribute-models

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [the flask-sqlalchemy docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/) your models need to derive from `db.Model` without the trailing `s`

> Furthermore it provides a class called `Model` that is a declarative base which can be used to declare models:

Comment: File "C:\Users\areb fg\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 2711, in __init__
self._validate_dialect_kwargs(dialect_kw)
  File "C:\Users\areb fg\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 289, in _validate_dialect_kwargs
    "named <dialectname>_<argument>, got '%s'" % k
TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'nullable'

Comment: as it appears there are some other issues in the code, check the entire traceback (in the snippet you sent I don't see anymore issues with `db.Model`)

Answer (score 3):

It should be `db.Model` instead of `db.Models`.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error because there was typing mistake I made the s small in string method for datatype like

```
db.String()--->correct

db.string()--->Incorrect

name=db.Column(db.String(),nullable=False)
```

Hope this helps someone